# 2020 Toyota 4Runner lazy 1-2 shift

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, shifting, 4runner

Recently picked up a 5th gen 4runner with 50K miles and noticed that the transmission was acting like it was low on fluid, I'm pretty strict with maintenance and I'm a firm believer in changing fluids early rather than later especially with these sealed transmissions that more than likely has never had it's fluid level checked so I had the transmission flushed at a Toyota dealer who said they used a valvoline cleaner.

Trans flush fixed the initial concern and I'd say she shifts near perfectly but something that stands out is that under heavy acceleration the 1-2 shift is just garbage. Any other gear is solid and under normal acceleration the 1-2 shift is ok.

I have access to ALLDATA from a previous job and found that there are replaceable shift solenoids that look extremely easy to access so I'm tempted to throw in a shift solenoid. I also know that in general with vehicles valve bodies *can* go bad, I was looking for some knowledge from the community on possible causes for this poor 1-2 shift on hard acceleration.

Comment: I would think it could be either worn clutch packs or low line pressure. A worn valve body might exacerbate the issue. Could be any of these. I'm not an automatic transmission expert, so take this for what it's worth.

Comment: I hadn't considered clutch packs but that does sound more likely. Makes me wonder if another trans flush might help it. I've got maybe 1000 miles on this fluid right now and the 1-2 shift did gradually get better the first few months of driving I might give it another 10-20K miles and reassess.

Comment: Out of curiosity what would cause low line pressure?

Comment: I usually err on the side of caution with transmission flushes. They can cause more damage than good. Some would they remove buildup which is still keeping the transmission running. Once removed, there's too much gap and not enough goop. As far as line pressure, I think it can be caused from a weak fluid pump, excess clearances due to wear, or problems with the valve body. I'm not an expert on this stuff, though, so I wouldn't take my word as gospel.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I normally apply that line of thinking to higher mileage transmissions so with this one being so low I'm not as skittish. I think I'm just going to leave it for now and accept that's just how she drives,  I'd rather put the money towards other upgrades anyways.